# Cannot open Local file /dir1/file1 : No such file or directory: PERL code

Tags: perl

I am trying to read file contents and assign it to a variable. Pass the variable to the FTP so that it can ftp the file. The input contains multiple lines. Hence I am using a while loop.

When I execute the ode in the UNIX environment it says

```
"Cannot open Local file <file name> : No such file or directory
```

But I am able to see the file in the location.

Input File contents (cfilelistftpA):

```
sxa1:OUT047
axk1:OUT635
 ...
```

Here is the output on UNIX for ls

```
axk1: ls -lrt
total 596
-rw-rw-rw-  1 axk1 ptuser 599399 Jul 23 23:06 OUT635
sxa1@axk5hbz: pwd
/home/sxa1/udms/axk1

sxa1: ls -lrt
total 836
-rw-rw-rw-  1 sxa1 ptuser 844664 Jul 23 23:06 OUT047
sxa1: pwd
/home/sxa1/udms/sxa1
```

I am unable to figure out the issue. 
Any help is much appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Std;
use File::Copy;
use File::Path;
use Net::FTP;

# declare and initialize counter
my $lfile = "LogFile";
my $filelistftpA = "/home/sxa1/filelistFTPA";
my $cfilelistftpA = "cfilelistftpA";
my $newPath = "/home/sxa1/udms";
my $newUDrive = "X:\\udms";
my $host1 = "XXXX";
my $user1 = "XXXX";
my $password1 = "XXXXX";
my ( $drive1, $part4 ) = split /:/, $newUDrive;


open (LOGFILE, "> $lfile") or die "Could not open log file $!\n";

my $ftpfiles = Net::FTP->new($host1) or die "Can't open $host1\n";
$ftpfiles->login($user1, $password1) or die "can't log $user1 \n";
$ftpfiles->binary();

open (MYFILESA, "< $cfilelistftpA");
while (<MYFILESA>)
{
    chomp;
    my $fileline = $_;
    my ($dirnameisA,$filenameisA) = split /:/, $fileline;

    print LOGFILE "Dir name is: $dirnameisA\n";
    print LOGFILE "File name is: $filenameisA\n";
    print LOGFILE "$hour, $min\n";
#        $ftpfiles->cwd($part4);
#        $ftpfiles->cwd($dirnameisA);
    my $dstFilesA = "$newPath/$dirnameisA/$filenameisA";
    if (-e "$dstFilesA")
    {
            print LOGFILE "File Exists: $dstFilesA \n";
    }
    else
    {
            print LOGFILE "File does not Exists: $dstFilesA \n";
    }
    $ftpfiles->cwd($part4);
    $ftpfiles->cwd($dirnameisA);
    $ftpfiles->put("$dstFilesA");
    print LOGFILE "READING from FILE: $_\n";

}
$ftpfiles->quit();
close (MYFILESA);
close(LOGFILE);


Output by executing "perl testftp.pl"

Cannot open Local file /home/sxa1/udms/sxa1/OUT047 : No such file or directory
 at testftp.pl line 62
Cannot open Local file /home/sxa1/udms/axk1/OUT635 : No such file or directory
 at testftp.pl line 62

 logfile contents:

 Dir name is: sxa1
 File name is: OUT047
 File does not Exists: /home/sxa1/udms/sxa1/OUT047
 READING from FILE: sxa1:OUT047
 Dir name is: axk1
 File name is: OUT635
 File does not Exists: /home/sxa1/udms/axk1/OUT635
 READING from FILE: axk1:OUT635
```

Comment: this is the actual code.

Comment: If you are getting that error, then it is getting all the way to the $ftpfiles->put(...) okay, and the error is telling you the answer - the file path you gave it does not exist. As you're not posting the paths and directory contents, I doubt we can help.

Comment: Which line produces the error? 
Also you should read the perldoc for split. It should be "split(/:/, $fileline)".

Comment: Let me provide the paths and the file.... as you requested.

Comment: I also checking if the file exists it says the file does not exists, but when I do ls on the file path I am able to see the file.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is looking for files in:

```
my $newPath = "/home/san/udms";
```

Your `ls` listings and `pwd` commands are looking for files in:

```
/home/sxa1/udms/axk1
```

If you get the spellings consistent, you stand more chance of it working; if you get them correct, it will improve the chances of it working.

Comment: And it works, or it does not work?  Please trim the code (some more) to the bare minimum; there are a lot of unused variables, and references to undefined variables.  The commented out `cwd` operations aren't needed, either.  It would help if you showed exactly the messages produced, in the log file and on the console output, for the 2-file data file.

Comment: it does not work. when execute it "perl testftp.pl" here is the output                                                              Cannot open Local file /home/sxa1/udms/sxa1/OUT047 : No such file or directory
 at testftp.pl line 62
Cannot open Local file /home/sxa1/udms/axk1/OUT635 : No such file or directory
 at testftp.pl line 62.

Comment: contents of the logfile for checking if the file exists                                                              Dir name is: sxa1
File name is: OUT047
File does not Exists: /home/sxa1/udms/sxa1/OUT047
READING from FILE: sxa1:OUT047
Dir name is: axk1
File name is: OUT635
File does not Exists: /home/sxa1/udms/axk1/OUT635
READING from FILE: axk1:OUT635
                                                                                                                      but if I hardcode the path it is able to find the file and ftp it.   $ftpfiles->put("/home/sxa1/udms/axk1/OUT635");

Comment: Please: add the output to the question where you can format it, and not to comments where you can't.  Delete your comments when you've transferred the information, then make another comment here to drag me back again.

Answer (score 0):

The error *Cannot open Local file* you're getting is coming from `Net::FTP` when you do a `put`. This happens when `sysopen` cannot open the file name you've passed it. It's usually an indication that the file doesn't exist.

Go to that error message and copy that file name. The entire name including the directory. Now, paste that into an `ls` command:

```
$ ls /home/sxa1/udms/sxa1/OUT047
No such file or directory
```

If you get that error, then your file name you're trying to `put` is wrong. Take a look at it and see if you can figure it out. For example, I see `sxa1` twice in the path. Is that correct?

If the file does exist, then take a look at other possible issues:

- Is the file readable by you? If not, you're not going to be able to open it.
- Is there any whitespace in the name? The `Net::FTP->put` command may list the file, but you're not seeing the actual name.

If you still can't figure it out, put more logging information into your program. Change these lines:

```
$ftpfiles->cwd($part4);
$ftpfiles->cwd($dirnameisA);
$ftpfiles->put("$dstFilesA");
```

To:

```
print qq(Changing to directory "$part4"\n);
$ftpfiles->cwd($part4) or warn qq(Can't change to directory "$part4");
print qq(Changing to directory "$dirnameisA"\n);
$ftpfiles->cwd($dirnameisA) or warn qq(Can't change to directory "$dirnameisA");
print qq(Attempting to "put" file "$dstFilesA"\n);
$ftpfiles->put("$dstFilesA") or warn qq(Can't put file "$dstFilesA");
```

I am looking at the return status of each of these lines as they execute to see if I can figure out what could be going wrong.  I am putting quotation marks around file names. Maybe the file has a leading or ending space or maybe a carriage return character. Maybe a hidden Windows NL because the person who created this file did so on Windows, and you are executing this on Unix.

See what this gives you.

Also, you claim this is the program, but it's only 57 lines long. `Net::FTP` claims that this error is on line 62 of your program. Can you show us which line is giving you this error? I am assuming `put` is doing it, but that's only line #51.

Comment: Thanks that helped me. There was a additional space at the end of the file name like "/home/sxa1/udms/sxa1/OUT047 " instead of "/home/sxa1/udms/OUT047". because of the additional space it could find the file.